# Prestashop payment module override

Tags: payment-gateway, prestashop

I have one problem regarding module override. I have created my custom payment module for learning purpose and now I want to change cart amount to total placed order. But
 `$this->module->validateOrder` gives error for amount. Is there any way to override validateOrder function of PaymentModuleCore class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own class and override the function, for example :

```
class    MyPaymentModule extends PaymentModule
{
    public function validateOrder($id_cart, $id_order_state, $amount_paid, $payment_method = 'Unknown', $message = null, $extra_vars = array(), $currency_special = null, $dont_touch_amount = false, $secure_key = false, Shop $shop = null)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

And your module extends MyPaymentModule, not PaymentModule.

Comment: Thank you @AlexDeb for your reply. And as per my knowledge, I should put this MyPaymentModule.php file on "mymodule/override/classes/MyPaymentModule.php" right? Make me correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: No no, simply create a folder "classes" in your module folder, then when you need it :
    require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'yourmodule' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classes' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'MyPaymentModule.php');